# Fold for Binary Tree

Tags: haskell, binary-search-tree, fold

I have to make an implementation of a Binary Tree instantiate a typeclass:

```
class Set s where
    add :: (Eq a) => a -> s a -> s a
    remove :: (Eq a) => a -> s a -> s a
    exists :: (Eq a) => a -> s a -> Bool
    fold :: (a -> b -> b) -> s a -> b -> b

data BTree k v = Empty | Node k v (BTree k v) (BTree k v) deriving (Show)
```

All went well until I had to implement a fold for a binary tree. The issue I'm having is that I don't really know how to keep the type declaration of my function with a signature like this: `(a -> b -> b)` . I've implemented a fold but the function signature for my anonymous function has 1 accumulator and 2 values:

```
foldBST :: (v -> a -> a -> a) -> a -> (BTree k v) -> a
foldBST _ startval Empty = startval
foldBST f startval (Node k v left right) = f v (foldBST f startval left) (foldBST f startval right)
```

How can I have the anonymous function have a signature like `(a -> b -> b)` ? I can' thing of any other way than calling the fold recursively on the left and right child, but this will return a value of type `a`.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: In which way do you want to fold the tree? Should this fold mirror the recursive structure of the tree or is it something like regular list fold (essentially, an iterative, not recursive procedure) of the list constructed by tree traversal?

Comment: Well I just figured I'd use tree recursion in my fold. So yes, I would like to reflect the recursive structure of the tree.  But as you pointed out I might as well use iteration over a list representation of the tree, this would then require me to create a list of the tree?

Comment: You can either build the list explicitly or implement fold directly over your tree like this: `fold f st (Node _ v l r) = f v $ fold f (fold f st l) r`. Of course you can change the order in which you process `v` and subtrees. Though I think that explicitly building a list of values and folding over it would be clearer.

Comment: This is a a more functional-ish style of the code below! Excellent! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can introduce an intermediate result:

```
foldBST f startval (Node k v left right) = f v i
  where i = foldBST f j left
        j = foldBST f startval right
```

and if you don't like intermediate results, you can just inline them.

Comment: This was the correct answer indeed! Silly that hadn't thought of it! Thank you very much! I was stuck with the types!