# How to make a nullary data constructor in Haskell return True for null

Tags: haskell, null

I have an algebraic data type, say

`data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Empty`

I want `null` to return `True` for the `Empty` node; `False` otherwise.

For example,

```
> tree = Empty
> null tree
```

Right now, this gives the following error.

```
<interactive>:261:1: error:
    • No instance for (Foldable Tree) arising from a use of ‘null’
    • In the expression: null tree
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = null tree
```

Note that `null` does return `True` for `Nothing`.

```
> null Nothing
True
```

Comment: “this gives me an error” – what is the error? Always include it in a question, these error messages are usually quite helpful.

Comment: Added error message to the post.

Comment: When you have functions you're not familiar with, you can use ghci to explore things: e.g. `:t null`, `:info Foldable`, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`null`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:null) requires an instance of `Foldable`: `null :: Foldable t => t a -> Bool`

The easiest way to create an instance of `Foldable` for `Tree a` is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Empty deriving Foldable
```

Or in `GHCi`:

```
λ > :set -XDeriveFoldable
λ > data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Empty deriving Foldable
λ > null Empty
True
λ > null (Node 1 Empty Empty)
False
```

**Note**: The reason `null` return `True` to `Nothing` is because `Maybe` has an instance of `Foldable`.

**The long way**:

Instead of taking a shortcut using Haskell's *magical* extensions you can write the `Foldable` instance manually as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566101/fold-for-binary-tree), it's boils down to:

```
data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Empty

instance Foldable Tree where
  -- The minimal definition is "foldMap" or "foldr", I'm choosing "foldr"
  -- foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
  foldr _ b Empty               = b
  foldr f b (Node a left right) = f a (foldr f (foldr f b right) left)
```

Comment: How does `null` know to return `True` for `Empty` and not for the other instance? I do not see anything in the code that specified that.

Comment: @wsaleem `null` calls `foldr` with `True` as the default value and `const False` as the folding function. So if the folding function is applied at least once, we get `False`, otherwise we get `True`. So the question becomes how `deriving Foldable` generates the definition for `foldr`. And the answer to that is going to be something along the lines of: it calls the folding function on every field of type `a` and recurs on every field of type `Tree a` (or rather of any type `f a` where `f` is an instance of `Foldable`).

Comment: Right, I completely skipped over how `null` is derived from `foldr`, thanks for your explanation sepp2k! If you look at the [source code on hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#null) you can see it is defined as: `null = foldr (\_ _ -> False) True`